# Word to describe rule of nepotism

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy

If a rule of competence is *meritocracy*, is there a single word to denote a rule of nepotism, such as *nepocracy*?

Comment: Generally it's simply called _monarchy_; one of the features of a hereditary monarch is that there are a number of ennobled relatives of the monarch who need jobs, and a monarch who needs trusted subordinates. What is more natural than to put the two together? _Nepotism_ comes from the Greek word for _nephew_; the question is: Whose nephew? And of course the uncle is more powerful than the nephew, which is why the nephew got the job. Of course, the same is true of aristocracy, but pure aristocracies are very unstable.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think there needs to be a distinction between the type of government, which tends to be based on mechanisms and constitutions, and the attributes of the people in power. Any type of government can take on a nepotistic form.

Comment: @JOSH, can you elaborate your comment ?  I don't see that he's changed much

Comment: @amphibient - ok, no problem.

Comment: @JohnLawler As an example of what happens to aristocracies, England of the 15th century - the period leading to the Wars of the Roses - is instructive. It is nowadays given the name [*bastard feudalism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastard_feudalism) by historians. The despotism of the Tudors put it down, but it all started to go wrong again when Elizabeth didn't produce an heir. But by then parliament was on the march.

Comment: monarchy has utterly no connection to nepotism.

Comment: A possible point of confusion is the description of _meritocracy_ as "rule of competence," suggesting that we pick _all_ of our leaders this way. No government that I am aware of does this. In modern democracies we elect leaders to some positions; the government is called a meritocracy if these leaders then appoint the _unelected_ officials on the basis of their intelligence and skills rather than political favoritism or family relationships. It seems to me it should be possible to combine this notion of filling appointed positions with other forms of choosing the people who do the appointing.

Answer (score 7):

There is the  term ***[nepocracy](http://definithing.com/nepocracy/)*** but  it appears to be mainly Indian English usage:

> - 1. Nepotism plus hypocrisy masquerading as Democracy.
> - 2. Any political system where almost all political leaders tend to be closely linked to other political leaders by blood or marriage.

(definithing.com)

From: [We live not in a Democracy but in a Nepocracy](http://babupaedia.blogspot.it/2014/08/we-live-not-in-democracy-but-in.html):

> - One of the most defining narratives of present-day India is nepotism. Otherwise a simple term – a polite hark back to help out poor dear nephew(s) – that sounds and feels so innocuous, it is hard to believe how this cancer has metastasized and colonized every cell of Indian society. We see it everywhere in India today, even in places which proclaim to be the high priests of the rule of law, so much so that what ***we see is not democracy but nepocracy (or nepotcracy, if that’s easy on your tongue!) – the rule by nepotism***.

(babupaedia.blogspot.it)

From: [Maithripala Sirisena: A Case of ‘Much Ado about Nothing’](http://sangam.org/maithripala-sirisena-case-much-ado-nothing/):

> - ***The correct term for Sri Lankan brand of 'democracy' is nepocracy*** (a cross between nepotism and democracy) and nothing else.

(sangam.org)

Comment: Just to correct something in your quotation, the "poor dear nephews" of Popes and cardinals when the word _nepotism_ coined were actually the illegitimate sons of supposedly celibate clergy, adding an extra layer of hypocrisy and dishonesty.

Comment: I agree that this word is used only in India. Moreover, it is an incorrect formation: the stem of "nepotism" is "nepot-" not "nepo-". So if you really want to coin a word for "rule by nephews" it should be "nepotocracy".

Comment: @fdb People who coin portmanteau's are probably rarely aware of the linguistic derivations of the original word components, and even if they are they probably wouldn't care. The new word is most likely formed in a way that rolls off the tongue well, so long as it still evokes the original stems. Dropping the "t" hardly prevents anyone from recognizing the link with "nepotism".

Comment: This is an interesting curiosity about a fun political-slang term in InE.  Otherwise totally irrelevant.

Comment: @Malvolio I believe 'add' rather than 'correct' is the appropriate word.

Comment: @fdb -- personally, I like _nepotarchy_.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the term [oligarchy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oligarchy) which means

> a government in which a small group exercises control especially for
>   corrupt and selfish purposes

[Merriam-Webster]

Of course, *oligarchy* is not as opposite to the term *meritocracy* as *[anti-meritocratic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antimeritocratic) (political) system*. But a small group is usually chosen by the ruler based on nepotism and favoritism rather than on their merits.

Another choice is just using *anti-meritocratic system*.

> Another priority, particularly for Italy, is to overhaul the
>   regulatory framework to uproot a deeply **antimeritocratic system** that
>   hinders competition by protecting insiders in industry, education, and
>   the services sector.

[International Monetary Fund, Regional Economic Outlook, October 2011]